# Where is the 'Event Time Zone' option field in 5.47.2?

Tags: civievent

I'm setting an Event and am asked to set the Time zone in order to save/update the event but I don't see this field on 5.47.2.

Should this be activated somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate Advanced evvent extension and it works (even though the Time Zone in CiviEvent still need to fixed)